# Error TreeNodeException: execute, tree in PipelineModel.transform using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

So I am doing one-shot encoding in a pipeline and doing the fit method on it.

I have a data frame that has categorical as well as numerical columns, so I have one hot encoded categorical columns using string indexers.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler


categoricalColumns = ['IncomeDetails','B2C','Gender','Occupation','POA_Status']
stages = []

for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = categoricalCol, outputCol = categoricalCol + 'Index')
    encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=[stringIndexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categoricalCol + "classVec"])
    stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]
    
    
label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'target', outputCol = 'label')
stages += [label_stringIdx]


#new_col_array.remove("client_id")

numericCols = new_col_array
numericCols.append('age')


assemblerInputs = [c + "classVec" for c in categoricalColumns] + numericCols
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]


from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(new_df1)
new_df1 = pipelineModel.transform(new_df1)
selectedCols = ['label', 'features'] + cols
```

I am getting this error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2053.fit.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(client_id#*****, 200)
+- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[client_id#*****], functions=[], output=[client_id#*****])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(client_id#*****, 200)
      +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[client_id#*****], functions=[], output=[client_id#*****])
         +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[client_id#*****, event_name#27993], functions=[], output=[client_id#27980])
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(client_id#*****, event_name#27993, 200)
               +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[client_id#*****, event_name#27993], functions=[], output=[client_id#*****, event_name#27993])
                  +- *(2) Project [client_id#*****, event_name#27993]
                     +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [client_id#*****], [Party_Code#*****], LeftSemi, BuildRight, false
                        :- *(2) Project [client_id#*****, event_name#27993]
                        :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(client_id#*****)
                        :     +- *(2) FileScan orc dbo.dp_clickstream_[client_id#*****,event_name#27993,dt#28010] Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: **PrunedInMemoryFileIndex**[s3n://processed/db-dbo-..., PartitionCount: 6, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(dt#28010), (cast(dt#28010 as timestamp) >= 1610409600000000), (cast(dt#28010 as timest..., PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(client_id)], ReadSchema: struct<client_id:string,event_name:string>
                        +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]),false)


at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:197)


Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
```

My Spark version is `2.4.3`

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930591/spark-exception-in-thread-main-org-apache-spark-sql-catalyst-errors-package/59496073#59496073

Comment: @blackbishop, Thanks , Do you have good resources/references for Pyspark ML